ClusterAutoscaler on EKS
Has anyone deployed Cluster autoscaler on EKS With multiple nodegroups? I want the nodegroups to be individually configurable so I am using https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/examples/cluster-autoscaler-multi-asg.yaml.
But I do not want to hardcode the asg names. Is there a way to dynamically fetch and inject them? Or any other better approach please?

Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.
